# Best way for a job to update output from another job

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-computing, avro

Here is my scenario. I have a job that processed a large amount of csv data and writes it out using Avro into files divided up by date. I have been given a small file with that I want to use to update a few of these files with additional entries with a second job I can run whenever this needs to happen instead of reprocessing the whole data set again.

Here is sort of what the idea looks like:

- Job1: Process lots of csv data, writes it out in compressed Avro files split into files by entry date. The source data is not divided by date so this job will do that.
- Job2 (run as needed between Job1 runs): Process small update file and use this to add the entries to the appropriate appropriate Avro file. If it doesn't exist create a new file.
- Job3 (always runs): Produce some metrics for reporting from the output of Job1 (and possibly Job 2).

So, I have to do it this way writing a Java job. My first job seems to work fine. So does 3. I'm not sure on how to approach job 2.

Here is what I was thinking:

- Pass the update file in using distributed cache.  Parse this file to
  produce a list of dates in the Job class and use this to filter the
  files from Job1 which will be the input of this job.
- In the mapper, access the distributed update file and add them to the collection of my avro objects I've read in. **What if the file doesn't exist yet here? Does this work?**
- Use Reducer to write the new object collection

Is this how one would implement this? If not what is the better way? Does a combiner make sense here? I feel like the answer is no.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow below approach:

1) run job1 on all your csv file

2) run job2 on small file and create new output

3) For update, you need to run one more job, in this job, load the output of job2 in setup() method and take output of job1 as a map() input. Then write the logic of update and generate final output.

4) then run your job3 for processing.

According to me, this will work.

Comment: Each answer was technically right but I went with your approach. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Rig, If you need more help...raise the question and ping me.

Answer (score 2):

Just one crazy idea: why do you need actually update `job1` output?

- JOB1 does its job producing one file for date. Why not add it with unique postfix like random UUID?
- JOB2 processes 'update' information. Maybe several times. The logic of output file naming is the same: date based name and unique postfix.
- JOB3 collects JOB1 and JOB2 output grouping them into splits by date prefix with all postfixes and taking as input.

If date-based grouping is target, here you have lot of advantages as for me, obvious ones:

- You don't care abuot 'if you have output from JOB1 for this date'.
- You even don't care if you need to update one JOB1 output with several JOB2 results.
- You don't break HDFS approach with 'no file update' limitation having full power of 'write once' straightforward processing.
- You need only some specific `InputFormat` for your JOB3. Looks not so complex.
- If you need to combine data from different sources, no problem.
- JOB3 itself can ignore fact that it receives data from several sources. `InputFormat` should take care.
- Several JOB1 outputs can be combined the same way.

Limitations:

- This could produce more small files than you can afford for large datasets and several passes.
- You need custom `InputFormat`.

As for me good option if I properly understand your case and you can / need to group files by date as input for JOB3.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Mostly because I'm being mandated to do it this way. I agree that your method is superior

Answer (score 1):

For Job2, You can read the update file to filter the input data partitions in Driver code and set it in Input paths. You can follow the current approach to read the update file as distribute cache file.In case you want to fail the job if you are unable to read update file , throw exception in setup method itself.

If your update logic does not require aggregation at reduce side, Set Job2 as map only job.You might need to build logic to identify updated input partitions in Job3 as it will receive the Job1 output and Job2 output.